# Send Outlook Mail (2013) Not working

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am writing a script that at the end will send an email with logs from a completed process.  We use Outlook 2013 at work and I'm testing this on both outlook 2013 and Outlook 2010 with the same results.

The script will only generate a mailitem if Outlook is closed.  If it is open it throws a bunch of errors.  Anyone have an idea?

Here is the code:

```
############ Setup the outlook object#####

$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$datestr = get-date -Format yyyyMM
$message = $outlook.CreateItem(0)

###### Create an email and add the logs as attachments ######

$toaddress1 = "nospam@example.com"
$msub = "Monthly load - logs attached $datestr" 
$message.Recipients.Add($toaddress1)  
$message.Subject = "$msub"  
$message.htmlbody = "See attached logs for this months file load<br><br>" 

$filepath = get-childitem  "c:\path\log" | ? {$_.PSISContainer -eq $false} | select -ExpandProperty fullname
    foreach($file in $filepath) {

$message.Attachments.Add($file)
$message.display()
  }
```

Like I said, it works when Outlook is not open but with it open it generates the following errors from PowerShell:

```
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
{0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error:
80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005
(CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
At c:\scripts\mailtest.ps1:4 char:13
+ $message = (New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application)
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Exception calling "CreateItem" with "1" argument(s): "The RPC server is
unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)"
At c:\scripts\mailtest.ps1:7 char:1
+ $message = $outlook.CreateItem(1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At c:\scripts\mailtest.ps1:13 char:1
+ $message.Recipients.Add($toaddress1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At c:\scripts\mailtest.ps1:14 char:1
+ $message.Subject = "$msub"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At c:\scripts\mailtest.ps1:15 char:1
+ $message.htmlbody = "Jeff attached are the logs from this months load ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At c:\scripts\mailtest.ps1:20 char:1
+ $message.Attachments.Add($file)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At c:\scripts\mailtest.ps1:21 char:1
+ $message.display()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At c:\scripts\mailtest.ps1:20 char:1
+ $message.Attachments.Add($file)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At c:\scripts\mailtest.ps1:21 char:1
+ $message.display()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At c:\scripts\mailtest.ps1:20 char:1
+ $message.Attachments.Add($file)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At c:\scripts\mailtest.ps1:21 char:1
+ $message.display()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

I went on MSDN and could not find any updated methods for `Outlook.Application` so it looks like I'm doing this right or maybe a better way?  In this case Outlook is always going to be open in our environment.

Comment: Can you check File, Options, Trust Center, Trust Center Settings, Programmatic Access. You may need to open up the settings there to allow PowerShell to manipulate the Outlook mail files while it is open.

Comment: Thanks,  good idea but it appears to be set to allow pragmatic access to send mail on my behalf.  I also went as far as turning off my Anti-virus temporarily to see if that would allow it to work but it doesn't.  I have other VB scripts that do this successfully however.  Seems silly that it only works when Outlook is not a running process.    Thank you !

Comment: Oh and I may add this is happening on Both Windows 8.1 Enterprise (Work) and Windows 10 Professional.  I did some investigating and found this interesting article about it  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/06/24/432519.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Outlook only allows a single instance to be running at any time, especially for a non-exchange mailbox (it locks the PST).

You might consider checking for a running instance, and then retrieving the instance instead of creating a new one. Maybe something like this:

```psh
if (Get-Process Outlook) {
    $outlook = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')
} else {
    $outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
}
```

I haven't thoroughly tested this though.

Also, if Outlook is running under a different user account than this code, then it probably won't work anyway.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately I am still faced with the same errors.  I'm also able to open multiple instances of outlook if I right click the application on the taskbar and click Outlook 2013 - it fires off another copy in memory,  the same behavior works in Outlook 2010 as  well.   If I run your code on it's own just to debug I get an exception error:   (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))"

Comment: Ok I think I just figured it out!!  I was running Powershell in elevated privileges. So when I opened it up as a normal user my original process works as expected.    @briantist your message made me think more about what was going on so it made sense that I really wasn't running as "Me" but an Administrator.

Comment: Why are you using Outlook through a COM object to send a mail instead of using send-mailmessage? This could serious cut down the amount of lines in your script and increase reliability of the mailer. Using the EWS API (when using Exchange) is also a good option in a lot of these cases.

Comment: @bluuf I can't answer for the OP, and I'm not saying I would recommend Outlook automation, but some possible answers are that there is no SMTP server available that allows unauthenticated access, and that it may be undesirable to embed credentials in a script, or that there is no SMTP server locally at all (maybe they're not even using exchange). Just some speculation.